# Integrate Grails GORM with Spring

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm

I am not able to integrate grail's stand alone GORM with Spring.I am getting following compilation error.

```
Groovy:Unable to run AST transform org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.injection.EntityASTTransformation: missing class org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormValidationApi: are you attempting to use groovy classes in an 
 AST transform in the same project in which it is defined? http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin+2.0.0+FAQ#EclipsePlugin2.0.0FAQ-Q.DoesitsupportcustomASTtransformations%3F @ line 0, column 0.
```

and following jars in lib

```
grails-2.0.4.jar
grails-bootstrap-2.0.4.jar
grails-core-2.0.4.jar
grails-hibernate-2.0.4.jar
grails-spring-2.0.4.jar
grails-web-2.0.4.jar
```

Comment: Domingo Suarez has put up a sample recently about this - https://github.com/domix/gorm-standalone - have you found that yet?

Comment: I have the same error message when trying to get standalone GORM working, but only when I include the org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-test dependency. Domingo's example uses Spring's JUnit harness for testing, and I am trying to use Spock with Grails @TestFor annotations.